# Using C#, how can I pass an argument from one project to another

Tags: c#

I want to debug my **MainApp** which is a .NET console application which should receive argument from the user.
I can right click MainApp>properties>debug and add the required parameter there but this means setting them manually for each test.

I created another project (TESTER) to test **MainApp**.
I added a reference to **MainApp** in TESTER.
How do I call Main, in **MainApp** from TESTER and pass it arguments programmatically?

MainApp looks like this:

```
namespace MainApp
{
    public class GetData
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
```

However, from TESTER I can't call Main

```
var bmsDb = new MainApp.GetData.Main
```

is not vailable;

Comment: No, this assumes I call and exe. I do not want to call MainApp exe I want to call the project MAinApp to debug it

Comment: This is because the Main method returns `void` so it has no value to assign.

Comment: `new MainApp.GetData.Main` is trying to create a new instance of something, it should probably be just `MainApp.GetData.Main()` or `var x = new MainApp.GetData(); x.Main()`

Comment: _"**I want to debug** my MainApp which is a .NET **console application**...How do I call `Main`, in MainApp from TESTER and pass it arguments programmatically?"_ - instantiating an instance of `Program` cleverly renamed to `GetData` hardly counts.  That's not how to invoke a console app let alone "debug" it

Comment: You might want to consider posting as a _new question_ since your edits (5 mins after it was closed) arguably  takes your original question in a whole new direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know which class in `MainApp` contains the Main method (and that class is public), you can call it from your test project and pass arguments into it just like how you would call any other static method.

The Main method in your test assembly should look like:

```cs
public static void Main() {
    var arguments = new string[] {"arg1", "arg2"};
    MainApp.GetData.Main(arguments);
}
```

Comment: Tried it but I can't access Main from another project - please see update in my initial post

Comment: _"**I want to debug** my MainApp which is a .NET **console application**...How do I call `Main`, in MainApp from TESTER and pass it arguments programmatically?"_ - instantiating an instance of `Program` cleverly renamed to `GetData` hardly counts.  That is not how you test a console app